# Go mod replace (patch) only one package of dependency

Tags: go, dependencies, dependency-management, patch, go-modules

I have a dependency library in `go.mod` file, e.g. `foo.bar/dep`. I want to patch only one package of this dependency, e.g. `foo.bar/dep/pkg1` and place it somewhere in source repository, e.g. `./_patch/foo.bar/dep/pkg1`.

When I try to do this and replace it with

```
go mod edit -replace foo.bar/dep/pkg1=./_patch/foo.bar/dep/pkg1
go mod tidy
```

and my `go.mod` looks like

```
require (
  foo.bar/dep v1.0.0
)

replace foo.bar/dep/pkg1 => ./_patch/foo.bar/dep/pkg1
```

But when I build and run cmd, the code is still using origin `foo.bar/dep/pkg1` module instead of my patch.

Is it possible to replace only some particular package of dependency, or the only way is to replace the whole library?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to replace only some particular package of dependency [?]

No.

> [...] or the only way is to replace the whole [module]?

Yes, this is the only way.